# Arduino bat sensor registers too many times

Tags: java, arduino, sensors

I need to progam an Arduino for a project, and I thought I'd add something fancy, a LED color changing thingy. The LED has a sort of cyclus in which it changes colors, which takes about 40 seconds to do so. Though, the bat sensor, that makes the LED burn, registers the whole time and tells the LED a couple of times a second to go on, again. The LED never gets the time to change color and only stays the first color.

I have no idea how to fix this. I was trying to give the LED a delay or something, but apparently I did that wrong. The code so far is this;

```
//Pin which triggers ultrasonic sound.
const int pingPin = 13;

//Pin which delivers time to receive echo using pulseIn().
int inPin = 12;

//Range in cm which is considered safe to enter, anything
//coming within less than 5 cm triggers the red LED.
int safeZone = 10;

//LED pin numbers
int redLed = 3, greenLed = 5;

void setup() {
    //Initialize serial communication
    Serial.begin(9600);

    //Initializing the pin states
    pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    //Raw duration in milliseconds, cm is the
    //converted amount into a distance.
    long duration, cm;

    //Sending the signal, starting with LOW for a clean signal 2 staat voor reactie.
    digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);

    //Setting up the input pin, and receiving the duration in
    //microseconds for the sound to bounce off the object in front.
    pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
    duration = pulseIn(inPin, HIGH); //Documentation for pulseIn(): 
                                     //http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn

    //Convert the time into a distance
    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

    //Printing the current readings to the serial display
    Serial.print(cm);
    Serial.print("cm");
    Serial.println();

    //If het is groter dan 10 dan gaat het lichtje uit
    //else het is binnen bepaalde cm dan gaat het aan van 0 naar 255.
    if(cm>10)
    {
        analogWrite(redLed, 0);
    }
    else{
        analogWrite(redLed, map(cm,0,10,255,0));
        dela
    }

    if(cm>5)
    {
        analogWrite(greenLed, 0);
    }
    else{
        analogWrite(greenLed, map(cm,0,5,255,0));
    }

    delay(100);
}

long microsecondsToCentimeters(long microseconds)
{
  // The speed of sound is 340 m/s or 29 microseconds per centimeter.
  // The ping travels out and back, so to find the distance of the
  // object we take half of the distance travelled.
  return microseconds / 29 / 2;
}
```

But it still needs some kind of delay thing I think. I'm not sure what the sensor I'm using is called but it has two rounds with sensors in them, one sends and one receives, it measures how long it takes to receive back the sound and in my code I translate that to cm.

I hope you can help and understand what my problem is since my knowledge of this language is very poor.

Comment: It should not hurt, but setting up the input pin, line *pinMode(inPin, INPUT);*, should be moved out of function loop().

Comment: What frequency does the ultrasonic tranducer operate on? 40 kHZ? 100 kHz?

Comment: Are there some electronics associated with the ultrasonic tranducer (oscillator, amplifier, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `delay(ms)` to delay for 40 ms as required. That will shut the Arduino for 40 ms before it gets to process any data from the ultrasonic sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout value for [pulseIn](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PulseIn). Otherwise the program gets stuck in the line `duration = pulseIn(inPin, HIGH);` as you don't get the chance to send out another ultrasonic pulse if the previous ultrasonic pulse did not result in an echo.

In this case, the maximum range is 10 cm (20 cm travel distance for the sound pulse) so the timeout value can be set accordingly (s is distance, v is velocity and t is time):

```
s = v * t  => t = s / v = 2 * 0.1 m / 343.2 m/s = 582.8 µs
```

The speed of sound is assumed to be in dry air at 20 °C.

Allowing for the width of the outgoing pulse of 2 µs the total time would then be 584.8 µs.

Instead of

```
duration = pulseIn(inPin, HIGH);
```

use

```
duration = pulseIn(inPin, HIGH, 585);
```

---

Other notes:

1. The outgoing pulse is very short, intended to be 2 µs.
2. [digitalWrite() is quite slow](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,4324.0.html), on the order of 5 µs so the actual pulse may be longer than 2 µs. Even so, the ultrasonic transducer may not be able to start up in such a short time.
3. Even if the outgoing pulse is longer than you think it is, it is on the order of a single period (if the ultrasonic transducer operates at 100 kHz the period is 10 µs)

Try to experiment with longer ranges and longer outgoing pulses to be sure this is not the problem.